# Eclipse updates ruins Android XML layout editing

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I recently updated my eclipse installation with which I develop my Android apps.
Soon I found my layout files have lost the up and down arrows associated with each VIEW and LAYOUT which helps to organize my layouts.

I don't know whatelse the update, if anything, has messed up but I wonder and would appreciate any information on how to fix this issue so I can get my developments back on track, please.

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What kind of `up and down arrows`?

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of those arrows?

Comment: The image at http://www.mathcs.org/java/android/images/xml_converter_outline.jpg clearly shows what I am refering to. It was a standard feature until the update came along and roundly messed things up. It's the up and down arrows following the plus and minus images on the outline tab. Thanks for looking in.

Comment: Can anyone please help me. My eclipse update has removed the very vital control elements on the outline tab (shown here http://www.mathcs.org/java/android/images/xml_converter_outline.jpg ).I am referring to the plus, minus, up and down arrow buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a bug: **they have been officially removed**.

> The new editor in 8.x might look the same, but it's completely 
>   different underneath and we have added the +/- features back. 
>   the "-" button should be replaced by delete anyway. You can right 
>   click and choose delete or simply hit delete on your keyboard. 
>   The "+" option is indeed replaced by drag and drop. We've improved 
>   drag and drop significantly (and still improving it for the next 
>   version), and should be good enough that using "+" isn't needed. 
>   In some cases too, "+" isn't enough, you need more information to know 
>   where the item will be placed (like when dropping into a 
>   relativeLayout). 
>   (same thing with the up/down arrows)

([source](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/578a040448a92054/2f1b7954ae93ecb4))